# Cordova cannot find module

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, build, apk

I allready searched for solutions but couldn't find anything that works.

I'm trying to build / run apk with cordova but the emulator (and also my phone) won't start the app and fail on installation.
I tried to re-create the projet and re-install cordova but have this issue :

> Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova'

I also tried to do :

> npm cache clean

Nothing is working, can someone help me please ?
Thank you !

Comment: How did you install cordova? Did you installed it globally?

Comment: I installed it by using
> npm install -g cordova
And also tried 
> npm install -g cordova-lib
But I keep having the same issue

Comment: Please don't add your answer into the question; you make an answer by actually using the text box that says "Add an answer". Also, please do not put "resolved" into the title. The question is considered resolved when you accept or upvote an answer.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the similar situation, here is the error information:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

It happened after I upgraded my cordova with the command:

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Even when I ran the "cordova" command solely, same error I could get.

Finally solved by reinstall the cordova completely :

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
```

then

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case solved by removing and adding platform android again

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, this question is kinda old but I got the same problem and I "by-pass" it with this method.

[(SOLVED) Error: Cannot find module 'C:...\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova' #3301](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3301)

Actually, using  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

first of all, check the JRE installation on your computer, if is ok, follow this steps

1. `ionic serve`
2. `cordova clean android` (or IOS)
3. `rm -rf node_modules` (just delete node_modules folder)
4. `npm install`
5. `cordova build android` (without ionic)

It will add plugins to your project and also will compile it to an APK.

**EDIT:**

Just create another project, copy the "src" folder to the new one and ready to go!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run these commands

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Above commands are already answered but removing android and adding it again  is important
and then these :

```
cordova platform rm android/ios/browser
cordova platform add android/ios/browser
```

Worked for me, hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

[ss image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihtmF.png)

i tried :

```
npm uninstall -g cordova  

npm install -g cordova@latest
```

but, everytime i run `cordova`

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova'
```

im install manualy, open : `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` and create folder : `cordova\bin`

then i run

```
yarn add cordova
```

this solve, my problem