# Cordova 8 + iOS 4.5.4 = cannot find module "../cordova/platform_metadata"

Tags: ios, cordova

Since the latest update to v8 of Cordova, I cannot build anything on Mac.
I always get

```
(node 626) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '../cordova/platform_metadata'
```

I tried what was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806958/cordova-cannot-find-module) post but I get the same error.

I then did a verbose and it seems like the plugin required to build for ios is not working well

```
Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-swift-support for hook "after_prepare": plugins/cordova-plugin-swift-support/src/add-swift-support.js
Resolving module name for cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform_metadata => ../cordova/platform_metadata
(node:599) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module '../cordova/platform_metadata'
(node:599) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This was a bug in `cordova-plugin-add-swift-support`, just update it to latest version (1.7.1)

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
```

Comment: Thanks will try that after my work is done on this project :) upvoted

Comment: both android and iOS builds were giving error. fixed after trying this answer.

Comment: Been searching to resolve this error since two days. Resolved it finally. Thank you

Comment: This works in my case, but *only* after:
`cordova platform remove ios`, then update swift-support and reinstall `cordova platform add ios`.


`cordova clean` didn't worked for this.

Answer (score 11):

you need to downgrade cordova 7.1.0 until this issue is fixed. Do this:

```
 npm uninstall -g cordova
 npm install -g cordova@7.1.0

 cordova platform remove ios
 cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Made the change

Comment: Thanks, trying now, will post back

Comment: Thanks it works, will accept the answer. How did you know? How are we supposed to know???

Comment: @AjayReddy the issue was fixed two weeks ago

Comment: @jcesarmobile's post should now be the accepted answer. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If your running an ionic project that requires the swift plugin you'll need to add the --force flag:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support --force
```

Then run:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
```

Comment: Took an hour to got this right. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

That just happened to me (using Ionic). In Ionic, the issue comes from a plugin or node_module that is still using cordova/platform_metadata, which is deprecated.

If you are using Linux, in your project directory, try this in the command shell:

```
grep -iRn 'platform_metadata'
```

In my case, it was the plugin cordova-plugin-add-swift-support that was still using that, and I wasn't even using that plugin my project, so I deleted it manually. Problem solved. The issue seems to arise when a plugin is calling a module that no longer exists, so you have to either remove that plugin or update it.

Answer (score 1):

With Ionic 3 and Cordova 8.0.0 project.
Here are steps

1. ionic cordova platform remove ios
2. ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
3. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
4. ionic cordova platform add ios

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem, then upgraded Cordova to 7.1.0 work for me

Answer (score 0):

From my ionic project I did (bash):

```
grep -r 'platform_metadata' .
```

and found I had a plugin called `cordova-plugin-swift-support` was the culprit. I removed it and then added `cordova-plugin-add-swift-support` back in, and everything worked fine with cordova 8.0.0